# Winform User Control Like Dev Express Token Edit or Jquery Tags Input

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, telerik, token

I am working on Winforms with VB.Net.

The below paint diagram is a coarse depiction of my requirement.

[image: The Recatangular box with X is my required control]

When I click on the "Add Filter" button, a window opens containing a list of criteria. When i click one of the criteria, the window closes and the selected value is populated in a tag like control with ability to be removed when clicked over X

I have worked previously with J-Query Tags Input. I need a Winform control with such capability. I saw that DevExpress has such a control called TokenEditor but I don't have access to it.  I have access to Telerik.

The requirement is something on these lines
[image]

[image]

Any help in directing me in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your problem is. Why not using telerik `RadAutoCompleteBox` control?

Comment: Thank You very much. Noob Question. New to Winforms and Telerik

Comment: No problem. Everyone on this platform started at the bottom :) I'll give you an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use Telerik's `RadAutoCompleteBox` control. See the [Telerik documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/editors/autocompletebox/getting-started). One way to set the source would be:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>() { "Shawn Smith", "Toby Huck", "Steven Ratcliffe", "Dennis Smith" };
radAutoCompleteBox1.AutoCompleteDataSource = source;
```

If you start typing, the `AutoCompleteBox` pops up with your source items. If you want to separate the items with a special character, set the `Delimiter` property.

```
radAutoCompleteBox1.Delimiter = ',';
```

Default character is semicolon (`;`).

Comment: Glad I could help :)